# Understanding a proof in Probabilities with Martingales A1.5.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-explanation

I have trouble understanding a detail in the proof of the following theorem:

[image]

In particular, the proof (which I adjoin at the end) establishes the identities
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lambda(L^c\cap G) & = \lambda(L_2\cap L_1^c \cap G) + \lambda(L_2^c\cap G)\\
\lambda(L_2^c\cap G) + \lambda(L_2\cap G) & = \lambda(G)\\
\lambda(L_2\cap L_1^c\cap  G) + \lambda(L\cap G) & = \lambda(L_2\cap G)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Adding all three equations and subtracting
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\lambda(L_2\cap L_1^c\cap G) + \lambda(L_2\cap G) +  \lambda(L_2^c\cap G)
\end{equation}
from both sides gives the identity
$$\lambda(L\cap G) + \lambda(L^c\cap G) = \lambda(G)$$
as wanted.

My concern regards in subtracting $(1)$. What if $(1)=\infty$? ***How can the proof be amended to deal with such case?***

---

[image: proof 1]

[image: proof 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}\color{blue}{\lambda(L^c\cap G)}+\lambda(L\cap G)&=\color{blue}{\lambda(L_2\cap L_1^c\cap G)+\lambda(L_2^c\cap G)}+\lambda(L\cap G)=\\
&=\color{red}{\lambda(L_2\cap L_1^c\cap G)}+\lambda(L_2^c\cap G)+\color{red}{\lambda(L\cap G)}=\\
&=\color{red}{\lambda(L_2\cap G)}+\lambda(L_2^c\cap G)=\\
&=\color{green}{\lambda(L_2\cap G)+\lambda(L_2^c\cap G)}=\\
&=\color{green}{\lambda(G)}
\end{aligned}$$